# How to pass constant value on map function in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
val SCHEMA : Schema = ....
dStream.map(b => deserialize(bytes))

def deserialize(b: Array[Byte]): GenericRecord = {
      new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](SCHEMA)
        .read(null, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(SCHEMA, new ByteArrayInputStream(b)))
  }
```

I need to pass SCHEMA to map function. How I can pass SCHEMA variable in deserialize method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use currying

```
deserialize(schema: Schema)(b: Array[Byte]): GenericRecord = { ... }
dStream.map(deserialize(SCHEMA))
```

or binary function:

```
def deserialize(b: Array[Byte], schema: Schema): GenericRecord = { ... }

dStream.map(b => deserialize(b, SCHEMA))
```

Comment: thanks, it working. I was thinking that we can't send variable in map function before it runs on executor